# Windows Kernel `vector` class

Tags: c++, windows, kernel

```
#pragma once

#include <ntddk.h>

#include "move.h"
#include "testingMacro.h"
#include "util.h"

namespace anon {
namespace __vectorDetail {
//
// Global instance of a DPC queue of freeDpc
// which is necessary because we're not always at an
// IRQL level which allows us to call ExFreePool.
// It holds medium priority which should lead to us
// always freeing at APC_LEVEL.
//
inline KDPC kdpc;

//
// State holder for freeNowOrDpc, set to true
// once we initialize `kdpc`.
//
static LONG inited = 0;

//
// Function used in the initialization of `kdpc`.
//
static void freeDpc(PKDPC dpc, PVOID deferredContext, PVOID arg1, PVOID arg2) {
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dpc);
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(deferredContext);
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(arg2);

  ExFreePool(arg1);
}

//
// Function used to handle freeing memory, either
// frees now if possible, or schedules dpc.
//
static void freeNowOrDpc(PVOID ptr) {
  if (KeGetCurrentIrql() <= APC_LEVEL)
    ExFreePool(ptr);
  else {
    if (inited != 1) {
      InterlockedExchange(&inited, 1);
      KeInitializeDpc(&kdpc, freeDpc, nullptr);
    }
    KeInsertQueueDpc(&kdpc, ptr, nullptr);
  }
}
}  // namespace __vectorDetail

//
// Note: you are still responsible for IRQL safety despite there being
// safety for frees manually implemented through DPC.
//
template <class _Ty, ULONG _PoolFlags, ULONG _Tag = 'ANON'>
class vector {
 public:
  vector() : m_data(nullptr), m_size(0), m_capacity(0) {}

  ANON_NOINLINE_T vector& operator=(const vector& other) {
    if (m_data) __vectorDetail::freeNowOrDpc(m_data);
    m_size = other.m_size;
    m_data = (_Ty*)ExAllocatePool2(
        _PoolFlags, (m_capacity = calculateCapacity(m_size)), _Tag);

    // T must be copiable
    for (auto i = 0u; i < m_size; i++) new (&m_data[i]) _Ty(*other[i]);

    return *this;
  }

  ANON_NOINLINE_T vector& operator=(vector&& other) noexcept {
    if (m_data) __vectorDetail::freeNowOrDpc(m_data);
    m_data = other.m_data;
    m_capacity = other.m_capacity;
    m_size = other.m_size;

    other.m_data = nullptr;
    other.m_capacity = other.m_size = 0;
    return *this;
  }

  ANON_NOINLINE_T vector(const vector& other) { *this = other; }

  ANON_NOINLINE_T vector(vector&& other) noexcept { *this = move(other); }

  ANON_NOINLINE_T ~vector() {
    if (m_data) {
      for (auto i = 0u; i < m_size; i++) m_data[i].~_Ty();

      __vectorDetail::freeNowOrDpc(m_data);
    }

    m_data = nullptr;
    m_size = m_capacity = 0;
  }

  //
  // Front element
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T _Ty* front() noexcept {
    if (m_size > 0) return &m_data[0];
    return nullptr;
  }

  //
  // Back element
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T _Ty* back() noexcept {
    if (m_size > 0) return &m_data[m_size - 1];
    return nullptr;
  }

  //
  // Const front element
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T const _Ty* front() const noexcept {
    if (m_size > 0) return &m_data[0];
    return nullptr;
  }

  //
  // Const back element
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T const _Ty* back() const noexcept {
    if (m_size > 0) return &m_data[m_size - 1];
    return nullptr;
  }

  //
  // Operator[]
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T _Ty* operator[](size_t i) noexcept {
    if (i >= 0 && i < m_size) return &m_data[i];
    return nullptr;
  }

  //
  // Const operator[]
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T const _Ty* operator[](size_t i) const noexcept {
    if (i >= 0 && i < m_size) return &m_data[i];
    return nullptr;
  }

  //
  // Data
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T _Ty* data() noexcept { return m_data; }

  //
  // Const data
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T const _Ty* data() const noexcept { return m_data; }

  //
  // Preallocate for a size if the capacity is currently 0.
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T void reserve(size_t n) {
    if (!m_data || m_capacity == 0) reallocate(calculateCapacityExact(n));
  }

  //
  // Does placement-new by copy constructor
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T void pushBack(const _Ty& some) {
    if (auto capacity = calculateCapacityExact(m_size + 1);
        !m_data || m_capacity < capacity)
      reallocate(capacity);

    new (&m_data[m_size]) _Ty(some);
    m_size++;
  }

  //
  // Does placement-new by move constructor
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T void pushBack(_Ty&& some) {
    if (auto capacity = calculateCapacityExact(m_size + 1);
        !m_data || m_capacity < capacity)
      reallocate(capacity);

    new (&m_data[m_size]) _Ty(move(some));
    m_size++;
  }

  //
  // Calls destructor on back() then decrements size
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T void popBack() {
    if (m_size > 0) {
      back()->~_Ty();
      m_size -= 1;
    }
  }

  //
  // Gets size
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T size_t size() const noexcept { return m_size; }

  //
  // Gets capacity
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T size_t capacity() const noexcept { return m_capacity; }

  //
  // Calls destructors then sets size to 0
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T void clear() {
    if (m_data)
      for (auto i = 0u; i < m_size; i++) m_data[i].~_Ty();
    m_size = 0;
  }

  //
  // If size is 0, then frees and sets capacity to 0,
  // otherwise it copies to a buffer of capacity ceilPo2(size)
  //
  ANON_NOINLINE_T void shrinkToFit() {
    if (m_size == 0) {
      if (m_data) __vectorDetail::freeNowOrDpc(m_data);
      m_data = nullptr;
      m_capacity = 0;
    } else if (m_capacity > 0) {
      size_t oldCapacity = m_capacity;
      size_t newCapacity = calculateCapacity(m_size);
      if (oldCapacity <= newCapacity) return;

      reallocateExact(newCapacity);
    }
  }

 private:
  //
  // Calculate exact (non-rounded-up) size in bytes of N elements
  //
  ULONGLONG calculateCapacityExact(size_t n) { return sizeof(_Ty) * n; }

  //
  // Calculate size (rounded-up) in bytes of N elements
  //
  ULONGLONG calculateCapacity(size_t n) {
    return util::ceilPo2(calculateCapacityExact(n));
  }

  //
  // Copy operation
  //
  void copy(PVOID dest, size_t elements) {
    if (m_size > 0 && m_size >= elements)
      RtlCopyMemory(dest, m_data, calculateCapacityExact(elements));
  }

  //
  // Reallocate and copy to buffer of exact `capacity`
  //
  void reallocateExact(ULONGLONG capacity) {
    if (capacity < calculateCapacityExact(m_size)) {
      ASSERT(false);
      return;
    }

    PVOID newPtr = ExAllocatePool2(_PoolFlags, (m_capacity = capacity), _Tag);
    ASSERT(newPtr);

    copy(newPtr, m_size);
    if (m_data) __vectorDetail::freeNowOrDpc(m_data);
    m_data = (_Ty*)newPtr;
  }

  //
  // Reallocate and copy to buffer of capacity equal to ceilPo2(capacity)
  //
  void reallocate(ULONGLONG capacity) {
    reallocateExact(util::ceilPo2(capacity));
  }

 protected:
  _Ty* m_data = nullptr;
  size_t m_size = 0;
  size_t m_capacity = 0;
};
}  // namespace anon
```

Some notes:

1. It looks like I'm mixing allocators, however I also implement `new` and `delete` myself, therefore I know that allocators are not infact being mixed. One may argue that this is bad practice, and I don't disagree.
2. `ANON_TESTING_T` is a macro which expands to `__declspec(noinline)` in testing builds, to make debugging easier.